# The iff condition for the $f_{xy} = f_{yx}$ and $f(x,y)$ and integral.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let the real function, $f(x,y) : D \to \mathbb{R}  $

$(1)$ To make the statement "$f(x,y) \Rightarrow $ $f_{xy} = f_{yx}$" is true, What the condition should I add at the $f(x,y)$?

In my guess, Does it enough add the condition that all the second derivatives (e.g. $f_{xx}$, $f_{xy}$,...) are continuous?

$(2)$ Inversely,  Is the statement "$f_{xy} = f_{yx} \Rightarrow \exists f(x,y)$" always hold?

In my guess existence of the second derivatives itself implies the continuity, therefore antiderivative exits. Hence the statement is true. But don't have any confidence that is true.

$(3)$ Let the real-function $f$ and a curve $\gamma (\subset D)$

(Here the $\gamma$ $\in$ $C^1(I)$ for a interval, $I$)

Could we say "path independence of the $\int_{\gamma} f \bullet d\gamma $ $\iff$ existence of the antiderivative of the $f$"?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does setting $f$ equal to $0$ have to do with anything here? A $C^2$ function will have mixed partials equal. That's all you need. And of course having a solution to $f=0$ is totally irrelevant. Take, for example, any $C^2$ function $g$ and let $f = g^2 + 1$.

Comment: @TedShifrin, As your thankful advice, It surely irrelevant to constant, $c$ $s.t.$ $f(x,y) =c$. But Does it iff "$f(x,y) is$ $C^2 fucntion$" and "$its$ $mixed$ $partials$ $are$ $equal$"?

Comment: No, $C^2$ implies mixed partials are equal, but the reverse implication need not hold, I believe.